# How to modify Strapi admin panel with custom CSS?

Tags: css, strapi

I'm a UI/UX designer who has to modify Strapi admin panel for specific needs especially for the admin panel UI color.

How do I modify the CSS style in Strapi admin panel? On which directory do I have to access to modify the Strapi admin panel CSS style? Thank you in advance.